# How can I prevent changes to shared CloudKit zones from causing redundant CKDatabaseSubscription updates?

Tags: ios, cloudkit

This is the scenario I am facing:

CloudKit Account A has a CKShare attached to a record, and Account B has joined the share. (this all works fine.)

Account B has a CKDatabaseSubscription subscribed to the container’s shared database. (this works fine too, and I get updates).

What is *strange* is that if account B makes a change to a shared record or creates one, the aforementioned subscription pushes a notification to the device signed into account B. This results in account B fetching zone changes including the changes just uploaded by the device that made the changes.

What I expected was for subscriptions to work like the private database, i.e. the device that made a change to the records is not informed of them.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: AFAIK, I am not getting pushes regarding "own" edits. Of course, the update token will still be old etc but that was explained in the WWDC talk(s).

Comment: @Jonny Ah! It may well be that I am doing something wrong then. That's good news. Is your situation the same as the one described, in which you are adding/creating records in a database shared with the account making the modifications?

Comment: Yes I am experimenting with something similar. I am building something similar to Notes app, but just with more specific features. Shared records should be able to be updated by more than one account.